# Determining the session with the highest max count

Tags: sql, count, max

I have a table that has the following fields:

- Visit_ID
- CPCCID
- Date
- Time_IN
- Time-Out
- Course
- LA_CPCCID

There are 3 sessions, 9-12, 12-3 and 3-6.

I need a script that will calculate which session has the most visitors.

I have this attached code that will determine the session # and the max count:

```sql
select Time_In ,
CASE
When cast(Time_In as time) >'12:00:00' and cast(Time_In as time) <='15:00:00' /* and date = cast(GETDATE() as date)*/ then 'Session 2' 

when cast(Time_In as time) >'3:00:00' and cast(Time_In as time)<= '6:00:00' /*and date = cast(GETDATE() as date)*/ then 'Session 3'

else 'Session 1'
end "sessions"
from Lab_Visits2;


select max(visit.cnt) 
from
(select course, count(course) cnt
from Lab_Visits2
group by Course) visit;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to return the session and course with the most visitors grouped by session/course.  If so, this uses a couple of `common-table-expressions` to select the sessions, and then groups by session and course to get the count of visitors.  Finally, using `row_number` to establish the max:

```
with cte as (
  select 
      case
        when cast(Time_In as time) >'12:00:00' and cast(Time_In as time) <='15:00:00' /* and date = cast(GETDATE() as date)*/ then 'Session 2' 
        when cast(Time_In as time) >'3:00:00' and cast(Time_In as time)<= '6:00:00' /*and date = cast(GETDATE() as date)*/ then 'Session 3'
        else 'Session 1'
      end session,
      course
    from Lab_Visits2
  ), ctecnt as (
  select session, course, count(*) cnt
  from cte
  group by session, course
)
select session, course, cnt
from (
  select session, course, cnt, row_number() over (order by cnt desc) rn
  from ctecnt
  ) t
where rn = 1
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/37614/6)

If I misunderstood and you only want the session with the highest count (regardless of course), then just remove the course field from all of  the queries.

Comment: it works and I did not need the date, but when I uncomment the comparison to current date(getdate()) it is not accurate.

Comment: @kahunabee -- not accurate, can you explain, does it error?  Do you have a field called `date` or are you using `Time_In`?  `Date` is a  reserved word and you'd need to enclose the field with brackets if that's the case...

Comment: I meant I did not need the class, sorry, but the date issue is puzzling, I appreciate this.

Comment: these are the fields in my table(just test data)

Comment: these are the fields in my table                                                                                                             09:15:00 11:15:00 2014-11-02
11:15:00 01:15:00 2015-03-02
10:15:00 01:15:00 2014-11-02
03:01:00 04:30:00 2015-03-02
12:30:00 01:00:00 2015-03-02
11:50:00 01:30:00 2015-01-01                                                                                                                 so when I run the code for only current date it should be session 2 with a count of 2, but I get session 1 with a count of 4( that is correct without date filter)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28843265/sql-using-entered-time-to-find-session-with-most-visitors  you can take a look at the question here and compare notes with each other.