# SQL, using entered time to find session with most visitors

Tags: sql, count, max, case, row-number

I have a query that I need to write. Lab assistants will enter the information for students coming to the lab for help.  the field are:

> Visit_ID, Student_ID, Visit_Date, Time_In, Time_Out, Course, Asst_ID.

There are 3 sessions for time_in entry

- `Session 1   9-12`
- `Session 2   12-3`
- `Session 3   3-6`

The query needs to determine which session on the current day had the most visitors. This is what I have so far:

```
with cte as
 (
  select 
      case
        when cast(Time_In as time) >'12:00:00' and cast(Time_In as time) <='15:00:00'  and Visit_Date = cast(GETDATE() as date)then 'Session 2' 
        when cast(Time_In as time) >'3:00:00' and cast(Time_In as time)<= '6:00:00' and Visit_Date = cast(GETDATE() as date) then 'Session 3'
        else 'Session 1'
      end session
      /*course*/
    from Lab_Visits2
  ), ctecnt as (
  select session,/* course,*/ count(*) cnt
  from cte
  group by session /*course*/
)
select session, /*course,*/ (cnt)
from (
  select session, /*course,*/ cnt, row_number() over (order by cnt desc) rn
  from ctecnt
  ) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: homework?  The exact same question was asked already.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28822877/determining-the-session-with-the-highest-max-count  Notice the sql fiddle in there.  you might want to fire one of those up, to show what is not working right in your code.  Or, at least say what specifically what is not working in your code.